# How to specify template class visibility for a T4 preprocessed template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I have started adding some preprocessed T4 templates to a VS2010 C# library project. They are implementation details only, and I would prefer to not have them exposed on the library's API. I have not found a way to set the template's generated class visibility to 'internal'.

Is there a way? (If there is, I assume it will be something obvious that I have missed)

Thanks in advance,

/AI/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aethon, 
Unfortunately there is no way to do this today short of post-processing the generated code in some fashion.

I'm looking at adding this for a future release of Visual Studio.  If you wanted to log a [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) issue for this, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Gareth. It is good to have a definitive answer. I will submit a Connect issue and post a link here.

Comment: Connect suggestion is posted here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632269/option-to-control-the-visibility-of-the-generated-preprocessed-t4-template-class

Comment: Unfortunately, I may not have done any good. It was marked as resolved right away...

Comment: That was my colleague Jean-Marc - our bug-tracking tool doesn't let us expose internally raised bugs on Connect, so you can't follow along as easily.  I can't remember if I can flip it around, so the internal one becomes a dupe of yours instead.  If I can, I will.

Answer (score 5):

VS2012 has `visibility="internal"` on template.